# Data binding in Polmyer's <test-fixture>

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to test a custom Polymer element using their [web-component-tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester). Many of the examples make use of [test-fixture](https://github.com/PolymerElements/test-fixture). I would like to test my custom element using databinding, but I'm struggling to get data binding to work.

Essentially, I want to take my custom element, assume that the variables are bound, and assert things about it. I'm trying to follow the example in the test-fixture README. Note also that I originally posted this question [on their issue tracker](https://github.com/PolymerElements/test-fixture/issues/33) before realizing that Stack Overflow is probably a better place for it.

I'm defining a custom element in a my-element.html file, like follows:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    </style>
      <div id="txt-url" class="card-content">{{captureUrl}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: { captureUrl: String }
    });
  </script>
```

Here is the relevant portion of my my-element-test.html file:

```
<test-fixture id="my-fixture">
  <template>
    <my-element>
      <h2>seed-element</h2>
    </my-element>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>
  suite('<my-element>', function() {

    var myEl;

    setup(function() {
      myEl = fixture('my-fixture', {captureUrl: 'the url'});
    });

    test('heading is captureUrl', function() {
      var urlDiv = myEl.$$('#txt-url');
      // this will obviously fail, but used for logging purposes
      assert.equal(urlDiv, boundData.captureUrl);
    });
});
</script>
```

When I run this I see urlDiv in the error message (console.log wasn't working for me), and the div is empty, without captureUrl bound and inserted into the function. What am I doing wrong here? Am I mis-using Polymer? Mis-using test-fixture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the binding declaration in your template:

```
<test-fixture id="cached-page-summary-fixture">
  <template is="dom-template">
    <cached-page-summary capture-url="{{captureUrl}}">
      <h2>seed-element</h2>
    </cached-page-summary>
  </template>
</test-fixture>
```

Also, you're testing `<my-element>` but it's not present in the test fixture template. What do you want to data bind?

**EDIT**

Here's the most important change I made to your code:

1. The template inside test fixture must be [`<template is="dom-template">`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/test-fixture#data-bound-templates)
2. `fixture()` call was executed with wrong element id

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tpluscode/8f856398b3305d73885015a3fb67abb1), which works. Do `bower install` and then simply open test.html in your browser.

Comment: My mistake. `cached-page-summary` was supposed to be `my-element`. I've edited my question. Replacing `dont-know-where` with `capture-url="[[captureUrl]]` doesn't appear to fix it, as it remains undefined. I'm trying to inject data into `my-element` that I can test against.

Comment: Starting with your gist, I was able to get it working. Thank you very much. The two things wrong with my original code I believe were the lack of `is="dom-template"` and the failure to include `capture-url={{captureUrl}}` on the `my-element` tag in the test itself. Thank you!